# How is the most bottom bar called and how can i access it

Tags: python, scripting, interface

How is the most bottom bar called and how can I access it?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called status bar and can be toggled from the *Window* menu or with the operator

`Screen.show_statusbar`

[image]